# VB - save response as binary

Tags: vb.net, web-services, request, response, blueprism

Please see part of the code used to save response as a string to `resultData` variable:

```
Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim responseStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(responseStream)
resultData = sr.ReadToEnd()
```

It works correctly.

I have one case where the output is a binary file. How can I modify this code to save the reponse as a binary `ResultData` variable?

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: The purpose of a `StreamReader` is specifically to read text from a `Stream`. If you don;t want to read text, don;t use a `StreamReader`.  If you want to read binary data from a `Stream`, open a search engine and type in *"vb.net read binary from a stream"*. You don;t post questions here without having searched thoroughly first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many ways to do that. This one, is one of those. (This one help you also to show the progress) 
However (as advice) to monitoring progress there exists better approaches like Async methods etc.
In the example below I’m going to show you how to save e WebRequest as binary data.
***Note that, I’m based on your code and what you want, but, as I said before there exists different better approaches.***

```
       'here the file you want to save
        Dim LocalFilePath As String = "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\FolderXYZ\yourfileName.extension"

        Using reader As IO.Stream = request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
            Using writer As IO.Stream = New IO.FileStream(LocalFilePath, IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)
                Dim b(1024 * 2) As Byte
                Dim buffer As Integer = b.Length
                Do While buffer <> 0
                    buffer = reader.Read(b, 0, b.Length)
                    writer.Write(b, 0, buffer)
                    writer.Flush()
                Loop
            End Using
        End Using
```